# iOS7 CollectionViewCell not getting registered

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a collection view with custom collection view cells. I am making lot of computations inside the cells and hence it takes sufficient amount of time for the cells to be rendered. Hence, I created my cells manually(i.e even before collection view is created) using the custom cells and inside the method of `cellForItemAtIndexPath:`, I am just returning my cells. The solution is working correctly for iOS6, but for iOS7, it is not working and I am getting the error of

`*** Assertion failure in -[UICollectionView _createPreparedCellForItemAtIndexPath:withLayoutAttributes:applyAttributes:],`.

I have registered my cells and here is the brief amount of code.

MyMainVC.m

```
@implementation MyMainVC

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    NSArray *myArray = @[[MyCustomCell getCellAtRow:0], [MyCustomCell getCellAtRow:1], [MyCustomCell getCellAtRow:2]];
    [self createCollectionView:myArray];
}

- (void)createCollectionView:(NSArray *)myArray
{
    MyCollectionView *coll = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyCollectionView" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
    [self.coll createCollectionViewWithEntries:myArray];
    [self.view addSubView:coll];
}

@end
```

MyCollectionView.h

```
@interface MyCollectionView: UIView

- (void)createCollectionViewWithEntries:(NSArray *)myArray;

@end
```

MyCollectionView.m

```
@implementation MyCollectionView

- (void)createCollectionViewWithEntries:(NSArray *)myArray
{
    self.myArray = myArray;
    [self.collectionView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"MyCustomCell" bundle:nil] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"MyCollectionView"];
    [self.collectionView setDataSource:self];
    [self.collectionView setDelegate:self];
    [self.collectionView reloadData];
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    MyCustomCell *cell = [self.collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"MyCollectionView" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell = [self.myArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}
@end
```

MyCustomCell.h

```
@interface MyCustomCell: UICollectionViewCell

+ (MyCustomCell *)getCellAtRow:(NSInteger)row;

@end
```

MyCustomCell.m

```
@implementation MyCustomCell

+ (MyCustomCell *)getCellAtRow:(NSInteger)row
{
    MyCustomCell *cell = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyCustomCell" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
    [cell.tableView reloadData];
    return cell;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Not getting called in iOS7.
    return cell;
}

@end
```

As you can see, there is tableView inside the collectionViewCell which I am reloading and then returning. Another thing is the method of `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is never getting called as well in iOS7.  One probability which I believed was registering of nib should have been done before the cells are created. So I tweaked the MyMainVC.m file and created the variable of `MyCollectionView *coll` as instance variable and then created the cell. But that didn't work as well.

MyMainVC.m

```
@interface MyMainVC()
@property (strong, nonatomic) MyCollectionView *coll;
@end

@implementation MyMainVC

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    self.coll = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyCollectionView" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
    [self.coll registerNib];
    NSArray *myArray = @[[MyCustomCell getCellAtRow:0], [MyCustomCell getCellAtRow:1], [MyCustomCell getCellAtRow:2]];
    [self createCollectionView:myArray];
}

- (void)createCollectionView:(NSArray *)myArray
{   
    [self.coll createCollectionViewWithEntries:myArray];
    [self.view addSubView:self.coll];
}

@end
```

Inside MyCollectionView.m, I added one method as follows.

```
@implementation MyCollectionView

- (void)registerNib
{
    [self.collectionView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"MyCustomCell" bundle:nil] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"MyCollectionView"];
}

@end
```

I removed the registering in other method of  `createCollectionViewWithEntries:`

Can anybody tell me what is going wrong? It is working fine for iOS6 but not for iOS7.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: I'm confused about why you implement `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` inside the cell and not in the table view controller.  You only implement `cellForItemAtIndexPath:` in the view controller, which isn't a method the tableview knows about.  On top of that, MyCollectionView is a UIView, not a UICollectionView.  I see a hodgepodge of mismatched code for collection views and table views.  Are you sure we have a consistent set of code here?

Comment: @David, No, MyCollectionView has a collection view inside the UIView. It is present inside the XIB. Inside the UICollectionViewCell subclassed cell, there is a table view present in the XIB. Again, don't get confused. They are two XIBs I am talking of. The code is consistent in that area.

Comment: Then where is your `collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:`?